# Remove an old namespace from a g.cs File?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2010, project-folder

I previously had a subfolder in my WPF application project called "Controls". It contained a WPF user control. I decided to move that user control to my "Views" folder. Since the original folder was empty, I decided to delete it from the project.

Because the user control and folder is removed I receive a compilation error because the user control used the `ProjectName.Folder` namespace and now nothing references it. MainWindow.g.cs is what references `ProjectName.Controls` in a using statement.

I know that *.g.cs are generated by VS and can't be edited because it will be overwritten. What do I do to not allow that namespace to be written to the g.cs file? I tried cleaning my solution/project and rebuilding but nothing has worked.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804172/old-namespace-still-in-g-cs-file-when-changing-namespace-of-a-referenced-class/4804270

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a local reference to the Controls namespace in my Xaml code (MainWindow.xaml). I removed the reference, cleaned the project and produced a successful build.

Comment: I had the same problem, but much more deeper. I had usage of old namespace in referenced ResourceDictionary.

Comment: You're king @chopikadze that was exactly my problem I've searched for hours with no luck until I gained upon your small comment...

Comment: Correct; it seems that if you read "YourClassName.g.cs" as "YourClassName.xaml", open this file, and correct the outdated namespace declarations, the problem is gone and bob’s your uncle.

Answer (score 5):

In your user control file,

In your ClassName.xaml, you must change the namespace as shown below

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="YourOldNamespace.ClassName"
    ...
    ...
/>
```

And in your ClassName.xaml.cs, you must change the namespace as shown below

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace YourOldNamespace{

   public class ClassName{ ....

}
```

In both the files, you must replace YourOldNamespace to some new namespace as needed.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that information in my question. I changed namespaces appropriately in the controls xaml & cs files. The problem was that my MainWindow.xaml referenced the old namespace and that is why MainWindow.g.cs had a generated using statement for the old namespace. I corrected the xaml and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with g.cs files in my projects before too. Since they are auto generated, I tend to just delete the file manually and rebuild.

Comment: future reference: you can delete "stale" files by cleaning a project or solution.

Comment: @jlafay, thanks. I sometimes forget about that due to issues I have with Clean in my current project's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget too, that you must check to see if the Build Action property when you click on the affected XAML file is set to PAGE (instead of resource). This is useful to know when you copy a XAML from another project using copy-paste to save time.

Answer (score 1):

Also look at App.xaml and all of your resource dictionaries. For whatever reason, VS 2012's replace in files / "Entire Solution" option didn't find the old namespace reference in App.xaml, had to manually change that. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change your Generic.xaml file too,

```
<ResourceDictionary 
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyOldNameSpace">
</ResourceDictionary>
```