# Old namespace still in .g.cs file when changing namespace of a referenced class

Tags: wpf

I have renamed the namespace of a referenced class and WPF compiler doesn't want to take it into account: it keeps prefixing MyOldNameSpace in .g.cs file:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute
     ("PresentationBuildTasks", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class MyClass: 
    MyOldNameSpace.MyReferencedClass, 
    System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector {
```

Why ? How to fix this ? What's this obscure .g.cs file ?

Answer (score 22):

Looks like you didn't change your `MyClass.xaml` file. There should be something like this on top of it

```
<MyClass x:Class="MyOldNameSpace.MyReferencedClass"
```

but should be "My**New**NameSpace.MyReferencedClass"

Comment: This.  Refactoring doesn't change anything in the .xaml files.

Comment: Refactoring does change my xaml (VS2008 & VS2010)

Comment: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OldNamespace" will also need correction in the XAML file

Answer (score 7):

Close the .g.cs file. You can even delete it.

The g stands for generated, VS generates the wireing up between the code and the Xaml in this partial class.

Clean the solution and rebuild. That should fix it.

Comment: How does one clean the solution? 
My problem was that it kept regenerating the file including the reference to the package I had since removed. In the end, there was a reference to a control/element I had replaced still in a page's XAML (After changing from WebView to WebView2 and replaceing the element, there was an orphaned `xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"` still in there). Could I have used an automated process to catch that?

Comment: Regular clean: right-click the solution and select Clean
Deep, hard clean. Close VS, delete bin and obj folders

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. It looks a bit different for me on the old VS 2019, I get a generic "Clean Solution" plus a sub-menu of "Analyze and Code Cleanup"

Comment: @BenPhilipp - you are absolutely right, there should have been a period between Clean and Deep in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to change your Generic.xaml file too,

```
<ResourceDictionary 
                   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyOldNameSpace">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case removing obj folder fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

Also check xmlns:local in Application.xaml. This had me going for a while...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another case is that the build action of your xaml is not "Page" but the other options.